# Windows mobile 6.1 device classic Psion vendor

Tags: windows-mobile-6

Could anyone please tell me how Enable/Disable GSM/GPRS Modem driver from code C++ or C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TAPI Library for NETCF, in order to activate / deactivate the modem.

Also you need permissions to perform operations over the modem.

For the TAPI Library I've used OpenNETCF.Tapi